# Is it possible to get the AST for a cpp file from clangd vscode extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, clangd

I'm writing a vscode extension, which is trying to communicate with vscode-clangd extension. I need the AST from a cpp file, more precisely **the type with occurences in file of a selected variable**, however

- I can't call the **clangd.ast** command, because there are only **restart**, **check for update**, **download** language server commands, also if I run the code
  `let clangdExt = vscode.extensions.getExtension('llvm-vs-code-extensions.vscode-clangd');`
  activating or not the extension itself
  `console.log('Exports: ' + clangdExt?.exports);`
  shows exports is undefined.
- I couldn't find a way to parse the **clangd** outputchannel, which outputs **lsp** messages from communication between the active vscode-clangd extension and the clangd daemon.

Comment: "Show AST" clangd.ast support is available in extension clangd v12 or higher. I have tried the latest [rc2](https://github.com/clangd/clangd/releases/tag/12.0.0-rc2) and it works fine.
Couldn't find a way to call exported functions from clangd, but the extension [source](https://github.com/clangd/vscode-clangd)  is very useful to create an lsp client for clangd daemon.